# "Request timeout" H12 Heroku error tying to access MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

This problem seems to be quite common but I've tried several things and I still get this error.

Alright, so I'm trying to deploy on app on Heroku with my DB on MongoDB Atlas but when I'm trying a register or login POST request I get this message in the Heroku logs :

```
2020-03-29T09:54:50.197717+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/users/register" host=sleepy-beach-03876.herokuapp.com request_id=87810d90-3e72-4ff7-929e-77157f1b4a12 fwd="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

**What i've tried** :

- Increasing connection timeout time
- Double check if my IP address is Whitelisted, it is
- Double check if the URI is correct, it seems correct
- Using Heroku Config vars

Here's the URI
`mongoURI : 'mongodb+srv://xxx:xxxxxxxx@clusterftr-wrdqy.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'`

I've tried this

```
mongoose.connect(db.mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
.then(() => console.log(`MongoDB connected... ${db.mongoURI}`))
.catch(err => console.log(err + db.mongoURI));
```

And this

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://xxx:xxxxxxxx@clusterftr-wrdqy.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("users");
  client.close();
});
```

*Please note that it's my first StackOverflow post and one of my first Node projects, so please be understanding and send me some feedbacks if you want to :)*

Comment: That's not your real password, is it?

Comment: No it's not ^^'

Comment: mongodb+srv is only supported with 3.6+ drivers, you might try using the old-style connection string to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I changed the URI format to the old-style one but I still have the same problem apparently

Comment: Check the whitelist to make sure the Heroku IPs are allowed.

Comment: It works ! You were right, I forgot to give access to other IPs... Thank you Joe !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright it works, I answer to my own post in case someone is having the same problem.

I just forgot to add Heroku IPs in the whitelist so they can access to the DB...

Comment: I am running to this same problem problem. I am using the add on called `PROXIMO` (in Heroku) which generates an IP. I took that i.e. `xx.xx.xx.155` into  `MongoDB atlas > Network Access > IP Whitelist`. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Hi, I don't know this add-on but maybe there's a way for you to find the IP of the Heroku server you're using.
My project is just a small personal project so I just put 0.0.0.0 to allow Heroku to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how related this is but I was getting the `H12 - Request Timeout` error. Most likely because my `.env` variables weren't accessible in Heroku.

In the settings menu for my app I added them in the Config Vars section and now it connects.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my dynos and it worked for me
[Please Check this Heroku Application Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crzYa.jpg)